# Cannot get UIMapView to "zoom"/setRegion: when the map is loaded for the first time

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a `UIViewController` that loads a map with a bunch of pins already on it. There's no issues getting the pins to appear, but I can't seem to get `MKMapView` to execute setRegion when the user first reaches the mapView. I've tried putting the code in every possible method that could work, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillLoad`, `mapViewWillStartLoadingMap`, `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap`, etc., to no avail.

And yet, it WILL "zoom" to the designated region if I return to the previous viewController and then go into the viewContoller containing the mapView again.

Is there a super secret way of doing this that I'm not aware of? Shouldn't calling `[mapView setRegion:(...) animated:YES];` be enough to get the map to "zoom"/update to show the chosen region??

Also, if anybody knows how to get the pins (I'm using `MKPointAnnotation` for mine) to animate dropping in as well as getting the map to animate zooming in, (neither are doing it, although I set both to animate....), I'd appreciate that info as well.

Thanks!

**Code:**

```
@implementation FindOnMapMapView
@synthesize mapView;
@synthesize mapViewTabBarItem;
@synthesize results;
@synthesize reverseGeocoder;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([defaults doubleForKey:@"latitude"], [defaults doubleForKey:@"longitude"]), MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.744494189288569, 0.744494189288569));

        mapView.region = mapRegion;
        [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated:YES];



NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(ThePlace *place in results)
        {
            MKPointAnnotation *addAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

            [addAnnotation setCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.latitude, place.longitude)];

            addAnnotation.title = place.placename;
            addAnnotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance: %@", place.distance];

            [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];

        }

        [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations ];
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([defaults doubleForKey:@"latitude"], [defaults doubleForKey:@"longitude"]), MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.744494189288569, 0.744494189288569));
        NSLog(@"Region Coords are: Latitude:%f, Longitude:%f", [defaults doubleForKey:@"latitude"], [defaults doubleForKey:@"longitude"]);
        mapView.region = mapRegion;
        [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: @J2theC Added the code as requested

Comment: When this view controller is first shown, what does the NSLog print for the coordinates?  When first shown, is the map showing the Atlantic Ocean?  If you hard-code coordinates into the setRegion (instead of reading from NSUserDefaults) does it work?  Where are the NSUserDefaults setDouble calls done?

Comment: @AnnaKarenina IT prints the correct coordinates, (I just checked them). Yes, it shows the location as being in the north atlantic, I set it in my main view controller which is several scenes behind and the first loaded, hard-coding ends in the same result, first load is to north atlantic, and finally, I was having issues getting CLLocationManager to give me the "users" (my own) coords until I placed the code in my first view, (main menu) which is several segues aways from the mapView which is where I retrieve the coordinates from NSUSerDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(firstPoint.coordinate, 2000, 2000);
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

This works for me.